# Bind Oxyplot to MahApps AccentColorBrush programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, mahapps.metro, oxyplot, caliburn

I'm working with MahApps and trying to get its accent color to automatically apply to an OxyPlot chart. I'm using Caliburn and setting up my LineSeries programmatically in my viewmodel as Such:

```
_bubbleSeries = new LineSeries
{
    StrokeThickness = 2,
    Color = {Binding AccentColorBrush} // <-- This line here would be nice
    CanTrackerInterpolatePoints = false,
    Title = "Bubbles",
    Smooth = true,
};
```

Binding to the AccentColorBrush would be easy in XAML, but OxyPlot won't allow me to set up a LineSeries in XAML so any advice on how to do this programmatically in my ViewModel would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the `AccentColor` via code behind

```
_bubbleSeries.SetResourceReference(ColorProperty, "AccentColor");
```

the benifit is, that this is `DynamicResource`, so it just changes if you change the accent or theme.

**EDIT**

After I learned that `LineSeries` isn't a `FrameworkElement` I can give another possible solution.

The `ThemeManager` has an event to react on the theme change.

```
ThemeManager.IsThemeChanged += ThemeManager_IsThemeChanged;

void ThemeManager_IsThemeChanged(object sender, OnThemeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // handle theme change
}
```

With these event arguments.

```
public static event EventHandler<OnThemeChangedEventArgs> IsThemeChanged;

public class OnThemeChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public AppTheme AppTheme { get; set; }

    public Accent Accent { get; set; }
}
```

So you can set the color like this

```
// this = maybe your window
var accentColor = ThemeManager.GetResourceFromAppStyle(this, "AccentColor")
// or
var accentColor = ThemeManager.GetResourceFromAppStyle(Application.Current.MainWindow, "AccentColor")

// initial
_bubbleSeries = new LineSeries
{
    StrokeThickness = 2,
    Color = accentColor,
    CanTrackerInterpolatePoints = false,
    Title = "Bubbles",
    Smooth = true,
};
```

And now after theme change

```
void ThemeManager_IsThemeChanged(object sender, OnThemeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // handle theme change
    _bubbleSeries.Color  = e.Accent.Resources["AccentColor"];
}
```

Hope this helps now!

Comment: Thanks, this suggestion sounds great, but unfortunately LineSeries isn't a FrameworkElement and has no SetResourceReference function.

Comment: Wow, yes that helped greatly. I've spent hours and couldn't come up with this solution. Thanks for going one step further and mentioning the IsThemeChanged event too!

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a MahApps theme in `App.xaml` eg Cobalt Theme

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Cobalt.xaml" />
```

you can access certain colours using the `ThemeManager` class

```
 var color = MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.GetAccent("Cobalt").Resources["AccentColor"];
```

Comment: Thanks, this will be useful, but first I want to find out what the current accent color is. E.g. how do we know that "Cobalt" is currently active?